# A question about a projective map in Karen Smith's "An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following example is taken from Karen Smith's book "An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry", pg. 45.

> Let $C=\Bbb{V}(zx-y^2)\subseteq \Bbb{P}^2$ be a plane conic. This is a projective variety. Consider the map $$C\to \Bbb{P}^1$$$$[x:y:z]\to \begin{cases} [x:y]& \text{if } x\neq 0\\ [y:z]&\text{if } z\neq 0\end{cases}$$

Why do we not have a map for the condition $y\neq 0$?

Comment: If $y = 0$, then either $x = 0$ or  $z = 0$ (on C). So it would be redundant. In other words, the patches $x \not = 0$ and $z \not = 0$ cover $C$.

Answer (score 2):

If $y \not= 0$, then $zx \not= 0$ and so (assuming you are working over a field) both $x \not= 0$ and $z \not= 0$.

Comment: So? You mean this possibility is contained in the other two maps?

Comment: Yes that is right. As AreaMan says in the comment, the two affine charts $\{ x \not = 0\}$ and $\{ z \not= 0\}$ form a cover of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y^2=0$, then $zx=0$, this implies that ($x\neq 0$ and $z=0$)  or ($z\neq 0$ and $x=0$) which appear in the case considered already.